# xHTML syntax question

Tags: xhtml

Is it proper if I place the  tag after the input tag or before or does it matter?

```
<label for="l">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="lname" id="l" />

<input type="text" name="fname" id="f" />
<label for="f">First Name:</label>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are valid XHTML, however for good accessibility it's probably best to have `<label>` first so it'll be described by a screen reader before reaching the input itself.

Comment: If the screen reader user tabs through the form, it doesn't matter which side (or even where) the `label` is, as long as it's associated with the `input`. But I agree, the `label`/`text` should be first. That's were most visual user are used to see it.

Answer (score 2):

I put the input tag inside the label tag:

```
<label>Name: <input ... /></label>
```

That way, the for attribute isn't needed.

Comment: Older versions of IE has a problem with implicit labels.

Answer (score 1):

no. It doesn't matter.  The input can be anywhere on the page for that matter.